# Adding IDs to nodes in a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have a view with many nodes.

I need to reference to 4 specific nodes from a menu. and scroll the view to these nodes.

The order could change, and new nodes could be added so I cannot use the class "row-4.. or row3".

I need to add a specific ID to that nodes. It would be great to add their 'nid' in the html code as ids.

How can I make it ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the view, add a "Node: Nid" field and check the "Rewrite the output of this field" box. In the "Text" box, enter something like:

```
<a name="[nid]"></a>
```